# ActiveRecord create: pass in an array of attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to know if there is a Rails way to create multiple records by passing in an array of attributes.

For instance, instead of

```
MyModel.create!(attr_1: some_attr, attr_2: 1)
MyModel.create!(attr_1: some_attr, attr_2: 2)
MyModel.create!(attr_1: some_attr, attr_2: 3)
MyModel.create!(attr_1: some_attr, attr_2: 4)
```

I would like to do something like:

```
MyModel.create!(attr_1: some_attr, attr_2: [1,2,3,4])
```

But it does not work. Is there a similar way to achieve this without looping?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According the documentation you can [`create`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class) records from an array of hashes:

> The attributes parameter can be either be a Hash or an Array of
>   Hashes. These Hashes describe the attributes on the objects that are
>   to be created.

```
 MyModel.create([{attr_1: some_attr, attr_2: 4}, {attr_1: some_attr, attr_2: 5}])
```

Comment: Is there a version of this that doesn't save to the database? e.g. `build`?

Comment: @fatuhoku there is no such version which doesn't save.

Comment: Note: this does NOT create a single query for those trying to build an efficient insert query.

Comment: For those looking for an efficient insert query: https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import

Comment: Is there a possibility that we can user `find_or_create_by` instead of `create` here?

Answer (score 6):

At the time the question was asked ActiveRecord did not have any built-in features to efficiently insert multiple records at once. As of today Rails 6 is the current stable release and it comes with `Model#insert_all!` which is a method for bulk inserting.

You'll find the documentation for it here https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-insert_all-21

It is worth to mention that Rails 6 also implements `Model#upsert_all!` which efficiently inserts or updates in case the the record exists.